# How do I make parent component stay while switching between other components in react router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So, I have an AdminScreen page where I have some headings and a ul and below that I want to define some links and when a user clicks on that link, I want to render some component (but I want the headings and ul of AdminScreen page to stay there).

In react router v5, I would just use switch and define my routes and it would work. But, I have no idea what to do with react router v6. I tried this:

```
 <ul className="admin-functions">
            <li>
              <Link to="/admin/userslist"> Users List </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/admin/pizzaslist"> Pizzas List </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/admin/addpizza"> Add New Pizza </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/admin/orderslist"> Orders List </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Routes>
          <Route path="/admin/userslist" element={
            <AdminRoute>
                <UsersList />
            </AdminRoute>  
        } />
        <Route path="/admin/pizzaslist" element={
          <AdminRoute>
            <PizzasList />
          </AdminRoute>
        } />
        </Routes>
```

But, it doesn't work.

Btw, AdminRoute is just the route for determining if the loggedIn user is admin. It's working fine on AdminScreen. Anyway, here's the code for it:

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const AdminRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const loginUserReducer = useSelector((state) => state.loginUserReducer);

  const { userInfo } = loginUserReducer;

  const useAuth = () => {
    const user =
      localStorage.getItem("userInfo") && Object.entries(userInfo).length > 0;
    if (user && userInfo.isAdmin) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const auth = useAuth();
  return auth?children: <Navigate to="/login"/>
};

export default AdminRoute;
```

P.S: [How do I use react router v6 to switch between components on one parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012607/how-do-i-use-react-router-v6-to-switch-between-components-on-one-parent-componen) doesn't answer my question

Comment: Sounds like the question you linked *did* help answer your question. I was also going to suggest converting the first code snippet into a layout route to render the header and links and wrap nested routes. See [Layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured it out:

In my App.js, add a wildcard to the link of admin screen component:

```
<Route path="/admin/*" element={
          <AdminRoute>
            <AdminScreen />
          </AdminRoute>
        } />
```

In AdminScreen component, change route paths to:

```
<Route path="userslist" element={
            <AdminRoute>
                <UsersList />
            </AdminRoute>  
        } />
```